# Does services provided by different companies for DDoS protection work well?

Tags: attacks, firewalls, webserver, ddos

Is it necessary to use any DDoS service provided by different web hosting provider and other people?
We know, they are running their business to provide security to thousands of web property. They are earning plenty of money from this B2B service.

Some are good at what they say and what they provide, like CloudC.me, Cloudfare etc.
While other may get you more frustrated than DDoS attacker. Am I right?

Can't we, as a web owner, resolve issue by ourselves?

Comment: Hi Nab, welcome to security.SE, I am removing the last two lines since they are really a new question (and un-related to the title). You should re-post those lines as a separate New Question.

Comment: Which 2 lines? I forgot.
Anyway, it's OK. No issue. :)

Comment: You can check the edit history by clicking the link "edited Jul 16 at 20:28"

Answer (score 3):

Distributed Denial of Service attacks work because they use multiple (sometimes thousands) of hosts sending traffic to your site to overwhelm your resources. This is not something you, as the target, can remedy. Cloud services, like the ones you mentioned, modify and limit the traffic to your site, and to do that, they need access along the path between your visitors and you.

Yes, there are ways to deal with DDoS on your own, but you can't stop or redirect the traffic. You can spin up a new site, on a new IP and URL, on a different hosting service, but your valid visitors won't be able to find you. It is also easy for the attackers to redirect their attack to the new site. You could change ports, shut down the service, or play with DNS tricks, but these are temporary solutions and have limited effectiveness.

"Is it necessary"? That's going to be up to you and the risks you have determined for your own site. If you can deal with a site that is overwhelmed for a while, then you do not need to pay for a service and wait out the attack. That decision is entirely in your hands.

Answer (score 3):

CloudFlare works very well. You can learn more about what they actually do to protect your site from this talk:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w04ZAXftQ_Y

It's not really possible to deal with such attacks on your own. Maybe in the earlier times, when such attacks were not very sophisticated, you could block off some traffic with your firewall, but now that's not really possible in case of serious DDoS attacks.

Another question is: are you really at risk for an DDoS attack, and what would be you losses if you would be attacked? For many web services, I would say the risk is relatively low that they could become a target of a serious DDoS attacks.

Comment: +1 for cost-benefit: is the cost of the service greater than the value that you would lose during a DDoS attack?

Answer (score 0):

> Can't we, as a web owner, resolve issue by ourselves?

**No**, simply because you have less bandwidth than your upstream provider... who may have less than a DDoS mitigation service.  The attackers throw lots of bandwidth-consuming traffic at you - if you're paying for a 100 Mbps Internet connection, and they throw 1 Gbps traffic at you, you'll be overloaded before the traffic even reaches you, leaving you no way to "resolve the issue."

See also [Can the IPS technology in a UTM prevent a DDoS attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87114/can-the-ips-technology-in-a-utm-prevent-a-ddos-attack/87128#87128)

Answer (score -3):

Yes, they work. No you cannot generally solve this yourself, but there are things you can do to mitigate SOME of the problem.

Comment: Can you tell me those things to use for mitigation?

Answer (score -3):

You can mitigate 99% of the DDOS attacks yourself with a front end load balancer

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all (and is provably incorrect, as pretty much all corporates have load balancers, and yet still need DDoS mitigation)

Comment: What happens when the load balancer is overloaded? DDoS needs to be mitigated a lot further up the chain than at the destination.